# Can UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition work on a UIImageView transition in a UIViewController?

Tags: objective-c

In the Apple Developer documentation, it says it works on transitioning one view controller to another. Can I use UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition to make a transition from a UIImageView object on top of a UIViewController?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

> A percent-driven interactive transition object drives the custom animation between the disappearance of one view controller and the appearance of another.

So it can only apply on two UIViewControllers transitioning.

I wrote a post [Draggable view controller? Interactive view controller!](http://imnotyourson.com/draggable-view-controller-interactive-view-controller/) about this topic.

A demo project as well: https://github.com/saiday/DraggableViewControllerDemo